# Does HTMLEditorKit render depending on IE version?

Tags: java, html, swing, internet-explorer, htmleditorkit

Is correct that `HTMLEditorKit` ignores tags such as seen below (used to emulate IE7 in a IE7+ browser) when rendering HTML content?

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```

Documentation on [`HTMLEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) mentions that it:

> ..supports HTML version 3.2 (with some extensions), and is migrating toward version 4.0. The `<applet>` tag is not supported, but some support is provided for the `<object>` tag.

So I shouldn't need to be concerned about IE rendering modes as these will be ignored anyway ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I shouldn't need to be concerned about IE rendering modes as these will be ignored anyway?

When written like that, they certainly will be ignored.

But then if the HTML relies on compatibility modes for display in actual browsers, I'd guess it would use styles that are too complex for the Swing styling engine.

Comment: I don't understand "When written like that, they certainly will be ignored." For "written like that" are you referring to "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">" ?

Comment: Yes, I meant when written as a `meta` element.  Any `meta` element the Swing rendering engine does not understand will be ignored.  Some HTM/CSS based 'compatibility mode' fixes were horrendously malformed and fragile, and depended on using known parsing/rendering bugs.  The Swing rendering engine would most likely crash while trying to parse the HTML/CSS hacks..